# How to bring a MatDialog to the front in an appropriate way?

Tags: angular, dialog, window, overlay

I'm trying to implement window features such as minimization and maximization etc. using MatDialog.
I want to bring the window to the front when it is focused/clicked.

At first, I tried to achieve it by manipulating z-index of all overlays. But it's dirty and tends to break easily.

The second thought is to reorder overlays, move the overlay of the focused window to the last position of cdk-overlay-container.

```js
const overlayRef = (dialogRef as any)._overlayRef as OverlayRef;
this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().appendChild(overlayRef.hostElement);
```

It does the trick, however, it also makes dialog not responding. It looks like Angular is losing track of the reattached dynamic component? The binding of (click) not working anymore.

Can somebody help to answer

1. How to reorder overlays in a correct way?
2. If reorder overlays is not ideal, is there any other way to achieve the goal?

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is way look appropriate enough

```
// CSS
.back-dialog {
  z-index: 999 !important;
} 

// TS
bringDialogFront(dialogRef: MatDialogRef<unknown>): void {
    const overlays = document.querySelectorAll('.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper');
    overlays.forEach((overlay) => {
      overlay.classList.add('back-dialog');
    });

    const dialog = dialogRef._containerInstance?.['_elementRef']
      ?.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

    const currentWrapper = this.getOverlayWrapper(dialog);
    if (currentWrapper) {
      currentWrapper.classList.remove('back-dialog');
    }
  }

  private getOverlayWrapper(
    dialog: HTMLElement | null,
  ): HTMLElement | undefined {
    if (!dialog) return;
    if (dialog.classList.contains('cdk-global-overlay-wrapper')) {
      return dialog;
    }
    return this.getOverlayWrapper(dialog.parentElement);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer this to get an idea. Don't miss to include dialog component as part of `entrycomponent`.

**https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularmaterial/dialog-component-example**

Comment: This link does not seem that helpful and does not address the specific issue the OP has raised. Moreover links can change, you should post an actual solution here if you have one.